# Change image resolution using imagick

Tags: php, imagick

How do i change image resolution using Imagick. I have learnt and
 notice that  setResolution change image density, but not
 resolution. i wish to make the image resolution to 12800 * 800 pixel
 resolution

```
    $image = new Imagick(); 
    $image->setResolution(72,72) ; // it change only image density.
    $image->readImage($img);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `setImageResolution`. More information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageresolution.php)

This in combination with `resampleImage` should give the desired result. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resampleimage.php)

```
$image = new Imagick(); 
$image->setImageResolution(12800,800) ; // it change only image density.
$image->resampleImage  (12800,800,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,1);
$image->readImage($img);
```

Copying the information found on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setresolution.php):

> This method uses the "convert -density {$x_resolution}x{$y_resolution}" parameter. However be aware, that Imagick::setResolution() is much more alike the "convert -density" option than Imagick::setImageResolution()
>
> It's very irritating that both Imagick::setResolution() and Imagick::setImageResolution() are introduced with "Sets the image resolution."

Comment: no it doesnt make changes to resolution. no matter what ever value i put inside setImageResolution. actually it has to read object first ...

Comment: @tomtom I added some more information on my answer.